# Show that if $f'(a) < 0 <f'(b)$, then neither $f(a)$ nor $f(b)$ can be the minimum value of $f$ over $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $f$ is differentiable over an open interval $I$. Suppose $a<b$ are two numbers in $I$ with $f'(a) < f'(b)$. Show  that if $f'(a) < 0 <f'(b)$, then neither  $f(a)$ nor $f(b)$ can be the minimum value of $f$ over $[a,b]$.

Intuitively this makes sense: $f$ must change concavity on $[a,b]$ and thus it will have a relative minimum point where the first derivative is $0$. Since $f$ isn't the constant function and the function changes concavity at least once, $f(a)$ nor $f(b)$ can be the minimum on the interval.

Is this reasoning fine or do I need to be more mathematical?

Comment: It sounds like you've considered this, but there could be _multiple_ concavity switches and thus multiple local extrema within the interval.  However, I think it's easier to think about the fact that if $f'(a) < 0$ then $f(a + \delta) \approx f(a) + f'(a)\delta < f(a)$ since $f'(a) < 0$ and likewise that if $f'(b) > 0$ then $f'(b - \delta) \approx f(b) - f'(b)\delta < f(b)$ since $f'(b) > 0$.  Which means that there are points immediately next to _both_ $a$ (to the right) and $b$ (to the left) which are smaller than both $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Comment: @Jared Do you mean a prime symbol on that second equation $f'(b-\delta)$?

Comment: No, I am approximating the function with the first derivative (a linear approximation).  Perhaps you haven't seen that yet (I'm not sure what level you are currently at).

Comment: If $f(a)$ (or $f(b)$) is a minimum value, then $f'(a) = 0$ (or $f'(b) = 0$). Contradiction.

Comment: @Adriano Yes, but there is more to the proof than just that. Also, you can't assume that the function is differentiable at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Adriano That's not necessarily the case because $a$ and $b$ are endpoints.  When finding absolute extrema you must check _both_ critical points _and_ endpoints (boundaries if we extend to higher dimensions).

Comment: @Puzzled417 The function is decreasing at $x = a$ thus immediately to the right of $a$, there is a smaller $f$ value.  Likewise, the function is increasing at $x = b$ therefore just to the left of $b$ there is a smaller value.

Comment: It sounds like $[a, b] \subseteq I$, in which case both are not endpoints and $f$ is differentiable at each point.

Comment: @Jared Using approximations is not very precise. Can you write an answer being more precise?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Without knowing what level you are asking and how far along you are (i.e. is this high Calculus AP/AB or is this is a college real analysis course), it's difficult to provide an intelligible answer.  Depending on the level, the proof requires differing levels of rigor.  For a high school Calculus course, saying it's decreasing/increasing is probably enough of a proof.  For a real analysis course, you would provide an epsilon delta proof (of sorts) to show a contradiction.

Comment: @Jared It doesn't need to be too advanced and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the meaning of sign of derivative.

*Let $f'(c) > 0$ then there is an interval $J$ with $c$ as an interior point such that if $x>c$ and $x \in J$ then $f(x)>f(c)$ and if $x<c$ and $x\in J$ then $f(x)<f(c)$.*

Same way we have corresponding result for the case $f'(c)<0$. For the current question note that $f'(a)<0$ and hence there is an interval containing $a$ where values of $f(x)$ to the right of $x=a$ are less than $f(a)$ so $f(a)$ is not the minimum value of $f$ in $[a,b]$. And since $f'(b)>0$ there is an interval containing $b$ where values of $f(x)$ to the left of $x=b$ are less than $f(b)$ and hence $f(b)$ is not the minimum value of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following picture where $a$ is the left and $b$ is the right:
[image]

$f'(a) < 0$ (given) therefore the function decreases as you move *immediately* to the right of $x = a$.  Therefore there are values of $f(x)$ immediately after $f(a)$ which must be smaller--**$f(a)$ cannot be a minimum**.

$f'(b) > 0$ (given) therefore there the function decreases as you move *immediately* to the *left* (running it backwards) from $x = b$.  Therefore there are values of $f(x)$ immediately *before* $f(b)$ which must be smaller--**$f(b)$ cannot be a minimum**.

This is *not* a rigorous proof--rather it is an *intuitive* proof (a proof sketch).  To be fully rigorous you need to show that these points I speak of (that are smaller) exist via an epsilon-delta proof (this is not an "easy" proof and I'm not completely sure how you would go about showing it).

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this *is* a valid proof. I think Littlewood would agree. Certainly Ramanujan would.

Answer (score 0):

First, by considering $f(-x)$ or $f(a+b-x)$, it's enough to show that $f(a)$ cannot be the minimum on $[a,b]$. Now the derivative of $f$ at $a$ is equal to the right derivative there,
$$0>f'(a)=f'(a^+)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h.$$
But this means that for all $h>0$ sufficiently small,
the numerator must be negative:
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\,\exists\delta>0\quad\text{so that}\quad
0<h<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon.$$
We only need to take some positive $\epsilon<|f'(a)|$
to guarantee that the fraction representing
average slope above is within $\epsilon$ of $f'(a)$
for any positive $h$ less than some $\delta$.
For example, take $\epsilon=-\frac12f'(a)>0$.
Then there is a $\delta>0$ so that for any $0<h<\delta$,
the inequalities hold. Fix $\delta$, and set $h$
to be any positive number less than $\delta$ such that
$a+h\in[a,b]$; for example, $h=\min(\frac\delta2,b)$.
But this means that
$$ f'(a)-\epsilon < \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h < f'(a)+\epsilon < 0 $$
$$ f(a+h)-f(a) < 0 $$
$$ f(a+h) < f(a) $$
so that $a$ cannot be the minimum, which completes the proof.

Comment: Oh god, so is the the rigorous epsilon-delta proof--I haven't had the time yet to look close enough to see if it's valid.